# Identifying and counting "correct" letters in a comma delimited string in R

Tags: r, string, duplicates, coding-efficiency

In this problem, I am trying to "score" a task from a computer administered questionnaire, where each person is asked to type 5, 3-letter words into a text box. The result in the `data.frame` looks like this:

```
dput(head(WRRsp, 10))

structure(list(Subject = c(100101, 100108, 100110, 100114, 100119, 
100123, 100133, 100148, 100155, 100159), WRRsp = c("Elk,Mop,Bat,Sop,Car", 
"Ely,Mop,Bat,Toe,Spy", "Bat,Mop,Spy,Elk,Top", "Spy,Bad,Toe", 
"Elk,Mop,Toe", "Eelk,Spy", "Elk,Toe,Mop,Box,Car", "Mope,Eik", 
"Ee,Elk,Mop,Bat,Fox", "E,L,K,Mop,Spy")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The correct responses are the following

1. elk
2. mop
3. bat
4. toe
5. spy

The idea is to create a 0-15 score taking into account points per letter for targets. For example, "Elk, Mop, Bat, Sky" would score as 11 out of 15 because "Sky" is not a correct word, but contains two of three appropriate letters. The major problem I'm encountering is that the **order of the words doesn't matter**, they could be entered in any order.

My first pass at this was to score based on position, so the targets would be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e | l | k |
| m | o | p |
| b | a | t |
| t | o | e |
| s | p | y |

An example scoring, if doing this by hand:

| Subject | WRRsp | 1st | 2nd | 3rd | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100101 | Elk,Mop,Bat,Sop,Car | 4 | 4 | 3 | 11 |
| 100108 | Ely,Mop,Bat,Toe,Spy | 5 | 5 | 4 | 14 |
| 100110 | Bat,Mop,Spy,Elk,Top | 5 | 5 | 4 | 14 |
| 100114 | Spy,Bad,Toe | 3 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
| 100119 | Elk,Mop,Toe | 3 | 3 | 3 | 9 |
| 100123 | Eelk,Spy | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 100133 | Elk,Toe,Mop,Box,Car | 4 | 4 | 3 | 11 |
| 100148 | Mope,Eik | 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 100155 | Ee,Elk,Mop,Bat,Fox | 3 | 4 | 3 | 10 |
| 100159 | E,L,K,Mop,Spy | 3 | 2 | 2 | 7 |

Some context: this is only one question in a large questionnaire designed to test for signs of cognitive impairment.

I can get really close with way too much code:

```
target1 <- c("e", "m", "b", "t", "s")
target2 <- c("l", "o", "a", "o", "p")
target3 <- c("k", "p", "t", "e", "y")

wrrsp_score <- WRRsp %>%
  separate_wider_delim(
    "WRRsp",
    delim = ",",
    names = c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5"),
    too_few = "align_start"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    col1 = paste(
      str_sub(w1, 1, 1),
      str_sub(w2, 1, 1),
      str_sub(w3, 1, 1),
      str_sub(w4, 1, 1),
      str_sub(w5, 1, 1)
    ),
    col1 = str_remove_all(col1, "NA"),
    # this stuff isn't really necessary
    col1 = str_trim(col1),
    col1 = tolower(col1),
    
    col2 = paste(
      str_sub(w1, 2, 2),
      str_sub(w2, 2, 2),
      str_sub(w3, 2, 2),
      str_sub(w4, 2, 2),
      str_sub(w5, 2, 2)
    ),
    col2 = str_remove_all(col2, "NA"),
    col2 = str_trim(col2),
    col2 = tolower(col2),
    
    col3 = paste(
      str_sub(w1, 3, 3),
      str_sub(w2, 3, 3),
      str_sub(w3, 3, 3),
      str_sub(w4, 3, 3),
      str_sub(w5, 3, 3)
    ),
    col3 = str_remove_all(col3, "NA"),
    col3 = str_trim(col3),
    col3 = tolower(col3)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    col1_e = ifelse(grepl(target1[1], col1), 1, 0),
    col1_m = ifelse(grepl(target1[2], col1), 1, 0),
    col1_b = ifelse(grepl(target1[3], col1), 1, 0),
    col1_t = ifelse(grepl(target1[4], col1), 1, 0),
    col1_s = ifelse(grepl(target1[5], col1), 1, 0),
    col1_score = rowSums(pick(col1_e:col1_s), na.rm = TRUE),
    
    col2_l  = ifelse(grepl(target2[1], col2), 1, 0),
    col2_o  = ifelse(grepl(target2[2], col2), 1, 0),
    col2_a  = ifelse(grepl(target2[3], col2), 1, 0),
    col2_o2 = ifelse(grepl(target2[4], col2), 1, 0),
    col2_s  = ifelse(grepl(target2[5], col2), 1, 0),
    col2_score = rowSums(pick(col2_l:col2_s), na.rm = TRUE),
    
    col3_k = ifelse(grepl(target3[1], col3), 1, 0),
    col3_p = ifelse(grepl(target3[2], col3), 1, 0),
    col3_t = ifelse(grepl(target3[3], col3), 1, 0),
    col3_e = ifelse(grepl(target3[4], col3), 1, 0),
    col3_y = ifelse(grepl(target3[5], col3), 1, 0),
    col3_score = rowSums(pick(col3_k:col3_y), na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  mutate(WRRspPerCharAC = rowSums(pick(ends_with("_score")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Where this fails, is with the second "o" in target2, it counts any "o" twice even if there are isn't anything to count (e.g., only two words entered). Two things: how to fix the duplicate issue, and how to make this more efficient/more streamlined, because what I have above seems overengineered and insane.

Comment: I think I would start with the string distances: `answers <- strsplit(DF[, "WRRsp"], ",", fixed = TRUE);  scores <- 3 - adist(tolower(answers[[1]]), target)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one attempt that looks to return the correct result with your sample data.  It relies on `pmatch()` to match the correct vector against the vectors of answers split on letter positions.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

targets <- list(c("e", "m", "b", "t", "s"),
                c("l", "o", "a", "o", "p"),
                c("k", "p", "t", "e", "y"))

dat |>
  mutate(score = tolower(WRRsp) |>
           str_split(",") |>
           map(
             ~ str_split_fixed(.x, "", n = Inf)[, 1:3] |>
               asplit(2) |>
               map2_dbl(targets,
                        ~ sum(pmatch(.y, .x, nomatch = 0) > 0))
           )) |>
  unnest_wider(score, names_sep = "_") |>
  mutate(Total = rowSums(pick(starts_with("score"))))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
   Subject WRRsp               score_1 score_2 score_3 Total
     <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  100101 Elk,Mop,Bat,Sop,Car       4       4       3    11
 2  100108 Ely,Mop,Bat,Toe,Spy       5       5       4    14
 3  100110 Bat,Mop,Spy,Elk,Top       5       5       4    14
 4  100114 Spy,Bad,Toe               3       3       2     8
 5  100119 Elk,Mop,Toe               3       3       3     9
 6  100123 Eelk,Spy                  2       1       1     4
 7  100133 Elk,Toe,Mop,Box,Car       4       4       3    11
 8  100148 Mope,Eik                  2       1       2     5
 9  100155 Ee,Elk,Mop,Bat,Fox        3       4       3    10
10  100159 E,L,K,Mop,Spy             3       2       2     7
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, I checked against 10 more hand calculated ones. Marking this one as the answer for now. Thanks!